# How to get info from pyscopg2 connection object?

Tags: python, psycopg2

How can I retrieve information about the host from the `connection` object?

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost'")
```

In this case, I would want to know which *port* is being connected to. In another case I may simply want to parse out the host name for logging.

I could parse the `connection.dsn` but there must be cleaner way since `psycopg2` has already done the work of parsing this information (or has it?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method `get_dsn_parameters` ([docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.get_dsn_parameters)) to get a dictionary containing all the dsn parameters, including the port. Also available as `.info.dsn_parameters` ([docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.ConnectionInfo.dsn_parameters)).

For example:

```py
port = connection.get_dsn_parameters()["port"]
```

or

```py
port = connection.info.dsn_parameters["port"]
```

Whichever you like better.